# error when running a compiled golang script

Tags: ubuntu, go, docker

I use [github.com/sideshow/apns2](http://github.com/sideshow/apns2) of specified revision in my project to send IOS push notifications. The **go 1.7.4** is inside of a docker container and I have compiled the app there and pulled the binary to the host machine. When I run the binary on the host it throws the next error:

```
Error Message: Post https://api.push.apple.com/3/device/{device_token}: dial tcp: lookup api.push.apple.com on 127.0.1.1:53: read udp 127.0.0.1:33891->127.0.1.1:53: i/o timeout
```

but running inside of a docker works as expected.

here is a part of code:

```
import (
    "os"
    "strings"
    apns "github.com/sideshow/apns2"
    "github.com/sideshow/apns2/token"
)

var ApnsClient *apns.Client

authKey, err := token.AuthKeyFromBytes([]byte(strings.Replace(os.Getenv("APNS_AUTH_KEY"), "\\n", "\n", -1)))
if err != nil {
    return err
}

Token := &token.Token{
    AuthKey: authKey,
    KeyID:   os.Getenv("APNS_KEY_ID"),
    TeamID:  os.Getenv("APNS_TEAM_ID"),
}

if os.Getenv("APNS_PRODUCTION") == "1" {
    ApnsClient = apns.NewTokenClient(Token).Production()
} else {
    ApnsClient = apns.NewTokenClient(Token).Development()
}

notification := &apns.Notification{
    Payload: {payload},
    Topic: {bundle id},
    DeviceToken: {device_token}
}

res, err := ApnsClient.Push(notification)
```

HTTP status in **res** is 200

any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Does it work if you build it on the host machine?

Comment: Looks like your DNS resolution works better inside docker than it does on your host.    Docker by default uses Google DNS (8.8.8.8).   Check your host.

Answer (score 0):

Your DNS resolution seems to have been compiled into your go-executable a mad way: 127.0.0.1:33891->127.0.1.1:53

What you see here is a port-binding of docker to your local host-dns server. This will not work on the host, but it does also make no sense having this "route" compiled into the go-executable.

Probably, you are compiling a static connection string into the APP, for the connection to the DNS server, i really cannot guess here.